# Phonegap push notfication plugin - Token Refreshed

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins

I use phonegap push notfication plugin that can be found here: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

and with this plugin i use GCM API.

My scenario is that:
any user in my application have a list of tokens that indicate the phone/phones he work with:

```
PKID | userID | registerToken
  1  |    9   |  someToken1
  2  |    18  |  someToken2
  3  |    13  |  someToken3
  4  |    13  |  someToken4
```

user can have multiple tokens but tokens can have only 1 user.
obviously i maintain this table with correct logic if user logged out or change phone etc...

the problem is with Token Refresh system of GCM.
according to GCM documentation they refresh the token periodically.
on native code you can use a listener called "tokenRefreshed".

1) GCM still refresh tokens , or the token is constant now ?

2) how can i use this listener with this plugin ?

3) how can i saftly know i have the last Register Token ID of the phone ?

4) even if i use "tokenRefreshed" , how can i know which token it replace on my table ? ( i need to know the previous token )

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, GCM token expires when you uninstall the app from the device. Hence for every installation store the registration ID in local storage which gets wiped when you uninstall the app.

Next, check if you still have the registration ID in your local storage. If not, do push registration which gives you new registration ID. Assuming you already know the userID from users login, you can just replace the old registration ID with the new one.

Push notification should work fine as long as the registration ID is recent to the new app installation.

I only know this much from my experience with GCM push service.

Comment: GCM token expires when you use "unregister" function too. what you suggest with save the token in local storage , but it feel to me not so safe and promise give right result. but the reall problame is the logic thing , my users can be loggin into the application from few another devices. like i the table i posted with the example , user not have only 1 device , hence i cant really know which tokenID i need to be replaced.

Comment: For that I added a new column in database table for device UUID. Instead of matching the user ID, I do a match to device UUID itself. For the case of unregister, I am sorry I cannot help you much.